# PyCUDA failing to include <curand_kernel.h> - error: no extern "C" linkage

Tags: c, cuda, pycuda

I'm trying to create a random number from a normal distribution inside a CUDA kernel, using PyCUDA (version 2011,2,2), in Python 2.7.3 on a Tesla C2075 (CUDA 5.0, V0.2.1221). However I am having issues in trying to simply include the curand_kernel.h header. I have created the most simple test case (shown below), but on compilation I receive the error.

> /usr/local/cuda/bin/../include/curand_kernel.h(568): error: this declaration may not have extern "C" linkage

Despite searching around I unfortunately still don't fully understand what the problem is, which has made it hard in trying to resolve it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import pycuda.driver as drv
import pycuda.compiler
import pycuda.autoinit
import pycuda.gpuarray as gpuarray
import pycuda.cumath as cumath
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule

gpu_test_source = SourceModule("""
    #include <curand_kernel.h>

    __global__ void test_kernel()
    {
        return;
    }

""")
```

Comment: Is whatever is at curand_kernel.h(568) `static`, that is, has file scope only?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you mean by static. At line 568 curand_kernel.h has `template <typename T, int n>`. Similarly for all other 20 errors in the compilation, the point to lines starting with `template`.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try the following?:

```
gpu_test_source = SourceModule("""
#include <curand_kernel.h>

extern "C"{
    __global__ void test_kernel()
    {
        return;
    }
}
""", no_extern_c=True)
```

Comment: Apologies I never responded to this, I don't think I ever saw this response.  I do believe I tried that at the time, but had no success. Thanks for the suggestion. I never solved this problem, but moved onto something else so don't know the solution.